# Magento 2 : CRUD, Invalid method _getResource() in model when Save

Tags: controllers, resource-model, magento2.2.0, crud

Magento CE 2.2.0; I created CRUD for model 'people' and save data in to database by controller for testing.

While i try to save by using controllor **Add**:

```
$_person = $this->_objectManager->create(\MagePro\Contacts\Model\People::class);
$_person->setName($person[PeopleTable::NAME]);
$_person->setSex($person[PeopleTable::SEX]);
$_person->save();
```

This process will meet error:

```
Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid method 
MagePro\Contacts\Model\People::_getResource in /home/dev- 
72/Work/Magento/Web/www/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php:395
Stack trace:
#0 /home/dev- 72/Work/Magento/Web/www/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Framework\DataObject->__call('_getResource', Array)
#1 /home/dev-72/Work/Magento/Web/www/app/code/MagePro/Contacts/Controller/People/Add.php(44): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#2 /home/dev-72/Work/Magento/Web/www/app/code/MagePro/Contacts/Controller/People/Add.php(25): MagePro\Contacts\Controller\People\Add->generatePerson('name', 'sex')
#3 /home/dev-72/Work/Magento/Web/www/generated/code/MagePro/Contacts/Controller/People/Add/Interceptor.php(24): MagePro\Contacts\Controller\People\Add->execute()
#4 /home/dev-72/Work/Magento/Web/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): MagePro\Contacts\Controller\People\Add\Interceptor->execute()
```

People Model:

```
<?php
namespace MagePro\Contacts\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class People extends AbstractModel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->_init(\MagePro\Contacts\Model\ResourceModel\People::class);
    }
}
```

People Resource Model:

```
<?php
namespace MagePro\Contacts\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
use MagePro\Contacts\Model\ConstantValue\DataTable as TablePeople;

class People extends AbstractDb
{
    public function _construct()
    {
       $this->_init(TablePeople::TABLE_PEOPLE, TablePeople::ID);
    }
}
```

Constant People Table:

```
<?php
namespace MagePro\Contacts\Model\ConstantValue;

class DataTable
{
    const TABLE_PEOPLE = 'tb_people';
    const ID = 'id';
    const NAME = 'name';
    const SEX = 'sex';
}
```

InstallSchema

```
class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
{
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    $this->createPeopleTable($setup);
    $setup->endSetup();
}

private function createPeopleTable($setup)
{
    if ($this->isExist($setup, PeopleTable::TABLE_PEOPLE)) {
        return;
    }

    $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable(PeopleTable::TABLE_PEOPLE)
    )->addColumn(
        PeopleTable::ID,
        DDL::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true]

    )->addColumn(
        PeopleTable::NAME,
        DDL::TYPE_TEXT,
        null,
        ['identity' => false, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => true, 'primary' => false]

    )->addColumn(
        PeopleTable::SEX,
        DDL::TYPE_TEXT,
        null,
        ['identity' => false, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => true, 'primary' => false]

    )->setComment(
        'Contacts Table'
    )->setOption(
        'type', 'InnoDB'
    )->setOption('charset', 'utf8');

    return $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
}

private function isExist($setup, $tableName)
{
    if($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($setup->getTable($tableName))){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Check my answer, Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 2):

While you provided limited code i can't look into this, But here you go.

> Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    if (!$installer->tableExists('your_table_name')) {
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('your_table_name')
        )
            ->addColumn(
                'entity_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary'  => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                ],
                'EntityId'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'status',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                '255',
                [],
                'Status'
            )
            ->setComment('Your Comment');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

> ../Model/YourTableName.php

```
 class YourTableName extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements TimelineInterface
{
const CACHE_TAG = 'your_table_name';

protected $_cacheTag = 'your_table_name';

protected $_eventPrefix = 'your_table_name';

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\ResourceModel\YourTableName');
}

public function getEntityId()
{
    return $this->getData(self::ENTITY_ID);
}

public function setEntityId($entityId)
{
    return $this->setData(self::ENTITY_ID, $entityId);
}

public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->getData(self::STATUS);
}

public function setStatus($status)
{
    return $this->setData(self::STATUS, $status);
}

public function getIdentities()
{
    return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
}

public function getDefaultValues()
{
    $values = [];

    return $values;
}
}
```

> ../Model/ResourceModel/YourTableName.php

```
class YourTableName extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
}

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('your_table_name', 'entity_id');
}

}
```

> ../Model/ResourceModel/YOurrTableName/Collection.php

```
class Collection extends 
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';
protected $_eventPrefix = 'your_table_name_collection';
protected $_eventObject = 'your_table_name_collection';

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\YourTableName', '{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\ResourceModel\YourTableName');
}

}
```

After follow above steps : Run `s:up`, `s:s:d -f`, 'c:f'

**Than after add some collumns in your table**

> ../Controller/YourTableName/Index.php

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 protected $_pageFactory;

protected $_postFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\YourTableNameFactory $timelineFactory
    )
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_postFactory = $timelineFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{


    $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
    $collection = $post->getCollection();
    foreach($collection as $item){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($item->getData());
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    exit();*/

    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
}
```

Hope it will help you.

For more you can check below references.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html

Happy Programming.. !!

Answer (score 1):

**Change resource model to**

> app\code\MagePro\Contacts\Model\ResourceModel\People.php

```
<?php

namespace MagePro\Contacts\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use MagePro\Contacts\Model\ConstantValue\DataTable as TablePeople;

class People extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    public function _construct()
    {
       $this->_init(TablePeople::TABLE_PEOPLE, TablePeople::ID);
    }
}
```

Now run command

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Follow the answer I will show this error.
'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in /home/dev-72/Work/Magento/Web/www/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:693\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/dev-72/Work/Magento/Web/www/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(406): Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractModel->beforeSave()\n..'